# How can dynamically remove element of form by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, element

I make a form with dynamic elements with Javascript.
I can add elements, but how can I remove them from form?
I can't solve problem. I'm confused! :(

My Code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
//+Element
function addElement(div) {
  var ni = document.getElementById(div);
  var numi = document.getElementById('numVal');
  var num = (document.getElementById('numVal').value -1)+ 2;
  numi.value = num;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.setAttribute('id',num);
  var unum="'"+div+"','"+num+"'";
  newdiv.innerHTML ='<input id="t" type="tel" placeholder="Tel.'+num+'" name="t'+num+1+'"><img id="del" onClick="removeElement('+unum+');" alt="del" src="images/del.gif" />';
  ni.appendChild(newdiv);
}
//-Element
function removeElement(divNum,div) {
  var d = document.getElementById(div);
  var olddiv = document.getElementById(divNum);
  d.removeChild(olddiv);
}
</script>

    <form>
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="numVal" />
    <div id="m">
        <div id="h125">
            <div class="fb">
                <input id="t" type="tel" placeholder="Tel.">
                <img id="add" Alt="add" src="images/add.gif" onclick="addElement('h125');" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Its a typo man! `var olddiv = document.getElementsById(divNum);`

Comment: ty. but not work yet!

Comment: What do your trying to remove, input or whole `div` with label? You pass 'h125' to all of your `removeElement` function call. Also you are trying to add multiple input with same `id="t"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? If so, when you mixed up ids in `removeElement` function.

```js
//+Element
function addElement(div) {
  var ni = document.getElementById(div);
  var numi = document.getElementById('numVal');
  var num = (document.getElementById('numVal').value -1)+ 2;
  numi.value = num;
  var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
  newdiv.setAttribute('id',num);
  var unum="'"+div+"','"+num+"'";
  newdiv.innerHTML ='<input id="t" type="tel" placeholder="Tel.'+num+'" name="t'+num+1+'"><img id="del" onClick="removeElement('+unum+');" alt="del" src="images/del.gif" />';
  ni.appendChild(newdiv);
}
//-Element
function removeElement(divNum,div) {
  var d = document.getElementById(divNum);
  var olddiv = document.getElementById(div);
  d.removeChild(olddiv);
}
```

```html
<form>
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="numVal" />
    <div id="m">
        <div id="h125">
            <div class="fb">
                <input id="t" type="tel" placeholder="Tel.">
                <img id="add" Alt="add" src="images/add.gif" onclick="addElement('h125');" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank u. I don't say good luck
Because you are successful!

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsById(divNum);
should read: document.getElementById(divNum);

You need to delete the 's' after element.
 **update**
Sorry, I didn't test before I answered.  When you declare `var unum` in your `addElement(div)` function, you have your variable names backwards.  It should read `var unum="'"+num+"','"+div+"'";`