# Is there a good way to delete the corresponding selection form?

Tags: javascript, html, parent-child

With this code there is a button were you can add a selection, this will add 2 input boxes and a button with a X in it, when you press the x button I want it to delete the corresponding selection form, Dose anybody Have a good idea on how to do it

```
 //adds more selection forms 
  var selectionAmmount = 0;
  var div;
  function addSelection() {
    var div = document.createElement('div')
    div.innerHTML = '<br>' + 
        '<input type="text" placeholder="Name Of selection">' + '<br>' +
        '<input type="number" placeholder="Price per s.y"">' + '<input type="button" value="x" onClick="removeSelection()">' + '<br>';

    document.getElementById("addSelection").appendChild(div);
    selectionAmmount++;
  }

  function removeSelection(t) {
    document.getElementById("addSelection").removeChild(document.getElementById("addSelection").childNodes[selectionAmmount - 1]);
    selectionAmmount--;
  }
```

```
 <div>
Has a selection: <input type="checkbox" id="selection" checked><br><br>
<selection id="hideSelection">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name Of selection" id="selectionName"><br>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Price per s.y" id="selectionPrice"><br>
  <selection id="addSelection"></selection>   
  <input type="button" value="+ selection" onclick="addSelection()"><br><br>
</selection>
```

This is a Link to were the code is being hosted if you want to see it in action: https://ogdens-flooring-estimator.hunterscott1.repl.co/carpet.html

If it would be helpful I can also post the whole entire file, just let me know I would greatly appreciate any help :)

Comment: Have a look here, there is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36575161/remove-dynamic-element-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign **id** to the **div** you create in **addSelection()**

```
 div.id=`selection${id}`;
```

In the **button onclick** pass the id

```
onClick="removeSelection(${id})"
```

In **removeSelection** function, get element by that **id** and remove it.

```
document.getElementById(`selection${id}`).remove();
```

Run the following snippet.

```js
var selectionAmmount = 0;
var id=1;
var div;
function addSelection() {
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.innerHTML = `<br><input type="text" placeholder="Name Of selection"><br><input type="number" placeholder="Price per s.y""><input type="button" value="x" onClick="removeSelection(${id})"><br>`;
  div.id=`selection${id}`;    
  document.getElementById("addSelection").appendChild(div);
  selectionAmmount++;
  id++;
}

function removeSelection(id) { 
  selectionAmmount--;
  document.getElementById(`selection${id}`).remove();
}
```

```html
<div>
Has a selection: <input type="checkbox" id="selection" checked><br><br>
<selection id="hideSelection">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Name Of selection" id="selectionName"><br>
  <input type="number" placeholder="Price per s.y" id="selectionPrice"><br>
  <selection id="addSelection"></selection>   
  <input type="button" value="+ selection" onclick="addSelection()"><br><br>
</selection>
```

Comment: I know this isn't really what the comments are for, but you seem like you have a lot more experience then I do, and I was just wondering what you thought about the program? I know that am not ready for a job in the programming industry, But I dont realy know how close I am. This is by far my project that am most proud of, and already I can see how impractical some of my begging code was written, but am trying to improve. any advice will be very happily accepted, Thank you so much for your help with my Original Question! That was extremely Helpful

Comment: Having the right knowledge and knowing what to apply at different scenarios is most important thing .You will get above things by practice .As for the learning of javascript and other courses you can get started here https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn